# DirectorySlash setting doesn't work with url without trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

`existingfolder` is a folder containing an `index.php` file. I have some rewrite rules to make `http://url.com/existingfolder/` redirect to that index.php. However, without the trailing slash, `http://url.com/existingfolder`, Chrome is stuck in loading and eventually leads to an error page.

I have tried numerous rules to get `http://url.com/existingfolder` (no trailing) work like the same as  `http://url.com/existingfolder/` (with trailing) with no success. My Apache version is 2.29 so I cannot use  `RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash`. I don't use `.htaccess` instead I put all the rules in the config file.

```
RewriteEngine on

###I have tried:

DirectorySlash off 

### I have also tried DirectorySlash on

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ - [L,R=404]

###

#The rest of my rules

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l

RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

#redirect to index page inside the folder 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]

#remove php extension
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This solution doesn't work at all. It makes things worse because `http://url.com/existingfolder/` has become inaccessible. Can someone point me out what's wrong with the rules?

Comment: What's the reason of `DirectorySlash off`?

Comment: @anubhava I have tried both `DirectorySlash off` and `DirectorySlash on`. None of them is working. I have also added an condition  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` before `RewriteRule ^$ - [L,R=404]`.

Comment: Keep `DirectorySlash on` and test in Chrome dev tool to see what "redirects" are taking place

Comment: @anubhava I am starting to suspect it has something to do with Haproxy which is listening on the standard 80 port. I re-opened port 3001 (Apache) in the firewall to test. Your rewrite rules should work, but for unknown reason it redirects to `http://url.com:3001/existingfolder/` instead of `http://url.com/existingfolder/`,which is not what I want. The page is broken because all of my css and js resources fail to load in  `http://url.com:3001/`. The chrome dev tool shows a status 301 code for the file.

Comment: Even I am suspecting some external entity like HaProxy changing default behavior of apache. Unfortunately I cannot test that on my end.

Comment: @anubhava I have added a rule to remove the port from the domain name. It looks okay but some other rules are unable to work. I'll make another thread for that.